# jQuery - Selecionar option e retornar valores

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sms_mensagem" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mensagem Pré Definida</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="selectpicker" id="men_cod" name="men_cod">
            <option value="">Selecione uma Mensagem</option>
            <? foreach($mensagens as $valor){ ?>
            <option value="<? echo $valor->men_cod; ?>"><? echo $valor->men_titulo; ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>                                                   
    </div>
</div>                                          

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sms_mensagem" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mensagem</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="sms_mensagem" name="sms_mensagem" rows="5"></textarea>
        <small class="caracteres">160 caracteres restantes.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

No primeiro select, eu tenho mensagens pré definidas, que são buscadas através de um jQuery no banco de dados. No momento que eu seleciono uma das mensagens, ele traz o resultado no campo sms_mensagem, até então OK, funcionando 100%.

Porém, se eu tornar a selecionar uma outra mensagem, ele não carrega a mensagem, ou se eu selecionar com valor null, e depois selecionar novamente uma mensagem pré definida, não vem retorno. O que poderia ser?

Segue o jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("change", function() {
        if(($("#men_cod").val())==''){
            $("#sms_mensagem").attr("disabled",false); 
            $("#sms_mensagem").val(''); 
        } else {
            $("#sms_mensagem").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
            var men_cod = $("#men_cod").val();
            var url = '<? echo base_url("index.php/sms/busca_mensagem"); ?>/'+men_cod;
            $.get(url, function(dataReturn){
                $('#sms_mensagem').load(url);
            });         
        }
    });           
});
```

Comment: O que vai sofrer o evento é o `document` ou o elemento que está no mesmo?

Comment: O que sofre o evento é o elemento, no caso, "men_cod", se ele for null, o campo é aberto pra digitar a mensagem, se ele for true, vem do banco de dados a mensagem pronta já, com disable pra ele não editar

Answer (score 3):

Você deve fornecer um seletor para o "on" da função:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
        if(($("#men_cod").val())==''){
            $("#sms_mensagem").attr("disabled",false); 
            $("#sms_mensagem").val(''); 
        } else {
            $("#sms_mensagem").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
            var men_cod = $("#men_cod").val();
            var url = '<? echo base_url("index.php/sms/busca_mensagem"); ?>/'+men_cod;
            $.get(url, function(dataReturn){
                $('#sms_mensagem').load(url);
            });         
        }
    });           
});
```

Nesse caso, ele vai funcionar como o esperado. Além disso, é melhor especificar algum elemento em vez de "document".

Comment: Neste caso, também não me retorna, quando eu retorno ele para o , e seleciono outra mensagem

Comment: Dá uma verificada se não tá cacheando, se for o caso use $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false });

Comment: Então, e outro detalhe, se eu não selecionar nenhuma e preencher uma mensagem avulsa, no POST não vem, mas se eu remover o script, ele retorna...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("change", function() {
        if(($("#men_cod").val())==''){
            $("#sms_mensagem").attr("disabled",false); 
            $("#sms_mensagem").val(''); 
        } else {
            $("#sms_mensagem").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
            var men_cod = $("#men_cod").val();
            var url = '<? echo base_url("index.php/sms/busca_mensagem");     ?>/'+men_cod;
            $.get(url, function(dataReturn){
                $('#sms_mensagem').html(dataReturn);
            });         
        }
    });           
});
```

Comment: Neste caso, também não me retorna, quando eu retorno ele para o , e seleciono outra mensagem